# Problem with lateinit in Android (Kotlin) - java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a small problem with `lateinit` and `java.lang.RuntimeException`. I've tried to solve it by myself and even look for the answer here, but with no success.

```
class NewsListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var onNewsInteractionListener: OnNewsInteractionListener

    private val mNewsMap: HashMap<String, NewsItem> = hashMapOf()

    val feedsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("feeds")

    val authListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener by lazy {
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
                feed_item_list.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    private lateinit var feedChangeListener: ValueEventListener
    val eventListener: ValueEventListener by lazy {
        object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                onUpdateRecyclerAdapter(p0)
            }

        }
    }



    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnNewsInteractionListener) {
            onNewsInteractionListener = context
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsitem_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        loader_news.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        feedsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                loader_news.visibility = View.GONE
                onUpdateRecyclerAdapter(p0)
                feed_item_list.scheduleLayoutAnimation()
            }

        })
        setUpRecycler()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        feedChangeListener = feedsReference.addValueEventListener(eventListener)
        QuizApp.fbAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        feedsReference.removeEventListener(feedChangeListener)
        QuizApp.fbAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener)
    }

    private fun onUpdateRecyclerAdapter(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (it in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val news = it.getValue<NewsItem>(NewsItem::class.java)!!
            mNewsMap.put(it.key!!, news)
        }
        feed_item_list?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun setUpRecycler() {
        feed_item_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        feed_item_list.adapter = NewsListRecyclerViewAdapter(mNewsMap, onNewsInteractionListener)
    }

    interface OnNewsInteractionListener {
        fun onUserSelected(user: UserItem, image: View)
        fun onLikeSelected(feedId: String, diff: Int)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have a RuntimeException:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.mylekquizapp/com.example.mylekquizapp.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property feedChangeListener has not been initialized
>
> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property feedChangeListener has not been initialized
>           at com.example.mylekquizapp.news.NewsListFragment.onStop(NewsListFragment.kt:86)

I have no idea how to solve it. Could anyone help with that issue, please.

Comment: Try to add `feedChangeListener= ValueEventListener` to onCreateView

Answer (score 1):

you have to do changes on your `onStop` method

```
override fun onStop() {
    feedsReference.removeEventListener(feedChangeListener)
    QuizApp.fbAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener)
    super.onStop()
}
```

you have to call the remove calls before the `super.onStop()`

Comment: App it's working even without the change. But I've change it anyway. 
Maybe something old was in the cache. Error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

If error is gone, that is great! Anyway, you should (have to) always check if not null before setting (using that variable) when using lateinit. You can check it with property isInitialized, which returns Boolean! That is in your function setUpRecycler(), where you initialize adapter and use interface!
I would go one step further and write more "kotlin way like:

```
 if (!:: onNewsInteractionListener.isInitialized) {
       onNewsInteractionListener = context
  }
```

And later also check if not null when init adapter! Hope it helps.